# Installing apk on jellybean 4.3 Android Emulator takes too long

Tags: android, apk, fiddler

Can anyone help me with this. I am trying to install an apk on android **emulator** from android studio (part of the development tools). However, it has been running for more than an hour. MY apk is very small only about 15mb.

```
VM Memory 600MB
RAM : 3GB
Disk space : 1GB
OS: Jellybean 4.3 
Architecture : ARM
```

Why is it still running so slow?

It is running fast if i change the OS to `Lollipop 5.0.1`. Lollipop 5.0 is out of the question as it does not work with fiddler. I cannot capture packets in Lollipop 5.0 with fiddler.

My constrains are:

```
ARM archetiture 
Fiddler
```

I am open to alternatives but i would have to stick to android emulator in android studio only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Android usage, belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Raptor Could you help me to migrate?

Comment: @Raptor - blatantly untrue.  The question concerns the android **emulator** which is a **Development Tool** (and thus explicitly on-topic per the rules of this site) - the Android site is for end-user issues only, which this is most definitely not! The question is on topic here, but would be off-topic there.

Comment: As for alternate solutions, note that regardless of the version of the emulator used, you should be able to capture packets on the hosting development machine - however, if the traffic is https or otherwise encrypted they might not be meaningful.